# running Powershell in batch file failed because of special character "|"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I recently started to some scripts in batch file to do some works but I failed when I tried to get some results from PowerShell then process it.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "ps= $FindProcess = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -like 'VNC viewer'};"
set "ps=%ps% $title = $FindProcess.MainWindowTitle ^| Measure-Object -Line;"
set "ps=%ps% $title.Lines"

echo %ps%
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell "%ps%"') do set "title=%%I"
:: For debugging and get the result
:: for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell "%ps%"') do echo %%I

echo %title% number of apps have "VNC viewer" title
```

but when run it i throw `'Where-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and when put `^` before `|` it result empty `%title%` and when uncommenting the debug section I shows this error

```
 $FindProcess = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -like 'VNC viewer'}; $title = $FindProcess.MainWindowTitle | Measure-Object -Line; $title.Lines
At line:1 char:124
+ ...  -like 'VNC viewer'}; $title = $FindProcess.MainWindowTitle ^| Measur ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token '^' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
ECHO is off.
 number of apps have "VNC viewer" title
```

Comment: The `echo` fails since you expose the string containing `|` unquoted; change `echo %ps%` to `echo "%ps%"` and it will work; in the next line, there are already quotes around `%ps%`, that is why it will work – after reading the error message and removing the unexpected character, of course…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out removing `echo %ps%` and do not putting `^` before `|` makes it work successfully but still don't know why echo it throws error!

Edited:
After reading [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034046/running-powershell-in-batch-file-failed-because-of-special-character#comments-71034046) comment I finally understood why. Actually `echo %ps%` will be parse to `echo what-was-in-the-variable-which-in-this-case-has-|-character` and this command also won't work without double quotation :) thank you

Comment: Though you are specifying part of the solutions to your problem, this does not really classify as an answer. Please delete it and either put is as an edit to your question or a comment below your question.